# Submitting a CSR and getting a new certificate with Get-Certificate

Tags: powershell, windows-server, pki

I am trying to get a new certificate from the certificate server, using the following approach:

```bsh
    $user = "MYDOMAIN\Administrator"
    $pw = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypw" -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$pw
    Get-Certificate -url https://cs.mytest.com/ADPolicyProvider_CEP_UsernamePassword/service.svc/CEP -DnsName $Env:COMPUTERNAME -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Template WorkstationTemplate -Verbose -Credential $credential
```

However I get back:

```bsh
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Get-Certificate" on target "https://cs.mytest.com/ADPolicyProvider_CEP_UsernamePassword/service.svc/CEP".
Get-Certificate : CertEnroll::CX509CertificateTemplates::get_ItemByName: Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)
At line:4 char:1
+ Get-Certificate -url https://cs.mytest.com/ADPolicyProvi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Certificate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.GetCertificateCommand
```

I am executing the command on the same machine as the test CS, to make sure there are no  networking issues, and I'm logged in as a domain admin. the certificate server is running as a Standalone CA on Server 2016.

What am I missing? Which object is it complaining about?

Comment: Are you able to get the certificate manually? See also: [CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND when importing certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33130655/1701026)

Comment: If by manually  you mean through the web interface or through the mmc, then yes, I have already issued my ssl certs for my test domain and a number of client certs. So the certificate server seems to be ok. I saw the other question, but get-certificate is supposed to do both the csr submission and the result retrieval, so why would it not be able to find its own csr? Unless I am misunderstanding what it does/

Comment: Well, it seems that the .NET API is not very flexible. I ended up doing calls to certreq, which worked okay. So I am no longer tracking this.